# Android Build failed with an exception

Tags: java, android, android-studio, github

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
  >   Could not find com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.12.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :app

[logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNiTH.png)

Comment: can you post your logcat

Comment: add more details to the question